# Easiest Way Of Getting Elements Unreadable by Simple HTML Dom Parser in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html-parsing, simple-html-dom

Let's say that a simple web application, like below, runs, utilizing Simple HTML Dom Parser.

```
<?php 
  include('simple_html_dom.php'); 

  $html = file_get_html('http://someurl.com');
  echo $html;
 ?>
```

As expected, everything comes up EXCEPT for one element, a `div` of class `.addedDiv`, which appears to be injected by JS. In the simplest and most inclusive way, can you please demonstrate how that one element can be retrieved with the minimal amount of code, hopefully with an example, 
**(update )** preferably inline and easy to implement for most people, be it with PHP, AJAX, or, I don't know, iFrame hack? Thanks in advance for any and all help.

**UPDATE:**

Also, if it helps, I don't actually need (or want) it outputted along with everything else. I just need an attribute from it to simulate some additional functionality. Therefore, if it is of any difference, I do not need to have to have a '$html' that outputs everything of a website to the screen (if I did, I'd just use an iframe).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use phantomjs module. you need to require install it.

phantomjs is command line utility, so in php you can execute it by `exec()` command and get expected foutput.

For more  you need to learn how to get content of HTML after modified by JS from here http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/content.html

Comment: Thanks for the advice, and I will be sure to look into it. However, for the sake of simplicity, is there any way of doing it completely inline (maybe using PHP or, more than likely, AJAX)? That would not only be preferred, but would also make the method more accessible, as I'm hoping that it would lead to more detailed and easy-to-replicate instructions.

Comment: Unfortunatley there is no way to execute Javascript code in PHP side... actually phantomjs is commmand line untility not a php function so you have to do by execute command by php code.